# Did I solve the Thevenin equivalent circuit left of the terminals correctly?

Tags: thevenin

[image]

I get $$v_{Th} = v_{ab} = v_{4Ω} = 0.8V$$

The solution is $$v_{Th} = v_{ab} = 1.2V$$

Isn't 1.2V the voltage drop over the 6Ω resistor?

[image]

Comment: You're right. It's wrong.

Comment: which 6 ohm resistor are you referring to? ... please label the resistors

Comment: The 6 ohm resistor in series with the 4 ohm resistor

Comment: You will appreciate that you have to learn to correct your own mistakes as an expert, but as a teacher, or in a new book , you can rely on your  readers.  All  consequences have a cost depending on qty in time or money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  The 2v source effectively eliminates the 6V source and the 6 ohm resistor in series with it since it is in parallel with those elements. Thus you are left with the 2V source across a simple voltage divider consisting of the 6 ohm resistor and the 4 ohm resistor. The voltage across terminals a and b will then be (4/(4+6)*2V or 0.8V. You are correct in that 1.2V is across the 6 ohm resistor.